# Get sum from more input radio button values

Tags: php, jquery, input, sum, radiobuttonlist

Can you help me ? 
It's part of my form. I want sum of values from more inputs (type=radio) after check it dynamically. I want count total price (variable - $res). 
I know that this is string, but when I was changed settype to int, it doesn't work.
Please, help me :)

```
                      <div class="wrapper_input">
                    <input type="radio" name="fee" id="radio1" value="300">
                    <label for="radio1">D1 &nbsp;300,00 €</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="wrapper_input">
                    <input type="radio" name="fee" id="radio2" value="150">
                    <label for="radio2">D2 &nbsp;150,00 €</label>
                  </div>
            <script>
                $('.wrapper_input input[type=radio]').on('change', function(event) {
                var result = $(this).val();
                $('.result').html(result);
                })
            </script>
            <?php
                $prem = "<span class='result'></span>";
            ?>
            <br>
                  <div class="case2">
                    <input type="radio" name="fee1" id="radio1" value="300">
                    <label>D5 &nbsp;300,00 €</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="case2">
                    <input type="radio" name="fee1" id="radio2" value="150">
                    <label for="radio6">D6&nbsp;150,00 €</label>
                  </div>
            <script>
                $('.case2 input[type=radio]').on('change', function(event) {
                var result2 = $(this).val();
                $('.result2').html(result2);
                })
            </script>
            <?php                   
                $prem2 = "<span class='result2'></span>";
            ?>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            TOTAL PRICE 
            <?php 
                $res = $prem + $prem2;
                echo $res;
            ?>
```

Comment: What is your intention to calculate the sum on server side?

Comment: It's form. I need this sum for save to mysql database.

Comment: And why don't you let the visitor finalize the sum on client side and after submit store it in your database?

Comment: It's good idea. But I don't know how can I make it :/

Comment: you are using php, like you would use JS - you can't get the value or text of it - you are just setting it as HTML - plus, you are trying to do math with strings. 
PHP happens on the server before/while the page is being loaded - you can't call it on change again.

Comment: remember - PHP is a hypertext preprocessor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based of the comment from questioner, here's a simple example to calculate the total price on client side:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var globalSum = 0;
   function summerize(formfieldObj)
   {
globalSum = 0;
formulaObj = $(formfieldObj).parents("form");
$(formulaObj).find("input[type='radio']:checked").each(function()
{
 globalSum = parseInt($(this).val()) + globalSum;
 $("#totalprice").html(globalSum);
 $(formulaObj).find("input[name='total']").val(globalSum);
});
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form name="bla" method="post">
   <div class="wrapper_input">
 <input type="radio" name="fee" id="radio1" value="300" onClick="summerize(this)">
 <label for="radio1">D1 &nbsp;300,00 €</label>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper_input">
 <input type="radio" name="fee" id="radio2" value="150" onClick="summerize(this)">
 <label for="radio2">D2 &nbsp;150,00 €</label>
  </div>
<br>
<div class="case2">
 <input type="radio" name="fee1" id="radio3" value="300" onClick="summerize(this)">
 <label for="radio3">D5 &nbsp;300,00 €</label>
  </div>
  <div class="case2">
 <input type="radio" name="fee1" id="radio4" value="150" onClick="summerize(this)">
 <label for="radio4">D6&nbsp;150,00 €</label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Pay">
  <input type="hidden" name="total">
   </div>
  </form>
  <div>TOTAL PRICE:<br><span id="totalprice"></span></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Hope it will help to lead into right direction.